# Ansible: How can I access a variable of other host?

Tags: ansible

How can I access a variable of other host? I'd like to access the slack_token varaiable of my localhost on the working_host.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    slack_token: 123123123
  tasks:
    - block:
      - name: test
        debug: msg="{{ slack_token }}"

- hosts: "{{ working_host }}"
  vars:
    slack_token: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['slack_token'] }}"                                                                                    
  tasks:
    - block:
      - name: test2
        debug: msg={{ slack_token }}
```

The error message:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field
>   'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that
>   is undefined. The error was: {{ hostvars['localhost']['slack_token']
>   }}: 'dict object' has no attribute 'slack_token'

Any idea?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? `slack_token` is a play-defined variable, not host-defined, so it is not accessible via `hostvars`.

Comment: I want to use the slack_token with other hosts too. how can I access a play_definied variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access `slack_token` from everywhere, either:

- pass it as extra variable with `-e slack_token=zzzz`
- define it in your inventory under `all` group

Comment: how can I define it under all group?

Comment: in `./group_vars/all.yml` file or `[all:vars]` section in inventory

Answer (score 2):

Just answered a somewhat same question in my previous post.

Here's what I used:

```
 set_fact:
    myVar: "{{ hostvars[groups['all'][0]]['slack_token'] | default(False) }}"
```

But you're using two plays in a playbook.
You can also try to copy a file to a machine stating the fact.